# Facebook Graph API - Get shared post reach by user

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Let's say we have a Facebook page with a post. Page followers come to our page and share that post. Is there a way I can get the reach/impressions of that post due to a particular user's share?

For example:
 - User A shared the post and reached 100 people.
 - User B shared the post and reached 20 people.

Comment: I don’t think so. Unless these users had given your app permission to read their personal posts, your app would not be able to _see_ their shares in the first place. And even if it does have permission - there are no such metrics available for posts on user timelines. At most you will be able to get some general about impressions / engagements via post insights, but I don’t think there is anything broken down to that detail level you want.

Comment: Ok, yeah they will grant permission via app.

Comment: Doesn’t change the fact that there’s no such metrics available for posts on user timelines to begin with.